# How to cancel a pending publication on Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, developer-console, rollout

Is there a way to cancel a pending publication on Google Play Developer Console? I have accidentally sent a wrong apk file and couldn't find a way to cancel it.

Comment: Release proper apk and push it. Hopefully not many people downloaded bad apk

Answer (score 38):

I'm too late, but it helps someone.

If the app is under review, upload the original or new APK. Google will automatically publish the latest version. Make sure that the new APK has higher Version Code.

If you don't want to upload a new APK file, you can control when updates are published.
Log in to your Play Console account and click on the "Publishing overview" item on the left pane. Next, click on the manage button.

[image]

Select the first option.

[image]

Google doesn't publish your app immediately.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me from pushing out a bad update lol!

Comment: but how do we remove that? or simple create a new bundle production release to replace it?

Comment: Thank you for the manage publishing hint! Saved me from pushing out a pretty bad update. Frustrating we cannot remove things from review with Google.

Comment: I uploaded the new app bundle from "Production" page.

Comment: @Mikey You can't remove it if it is under review (pending).

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22873363/1136253) but it could't be posssible for me because I couldn't change my app's bundle ID.

It says that:

> in Advanced Mode, you can cancel and upload again a new APK.

Answer (score 3):

Under Publishing overview -> Changes in review, you can now choose "Remove changes"