# Android: by accident we put our App in Production, be need to move it back to internal testing, how can we do that?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Currently the App is inactive because we don't want it to be in production yet.  But we don't see how can we activate the App, take it out of production and back into internal testing.
Really appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: This answer was helpful for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476097/how-to-cancel-a-pending-publication-on-google-play-developer-console

Answer (score 1):

You can't take an app out of production without unpublishing it altogether.

One option you have is to create a new app with a new package name.