# How to cancel a release/publication in google play console

Tags: android, google-play-console, production

I've rolled out a full release, but after release found a serious issues in app. Looked for many SO answers how to cancel a release but none worked. can't find any option to cancel that build before it goes live

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cancel a pending publication on Google Play Developer Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476097/how-to-cancel-a-pending-publication-on-google-play-developer-console)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long research we can't cancel a release when its rolled-out. The only thing we can do is change the publishing mode from auto to manual. So whenever the build is approved from google we decide to publish it store or not. This saved me from a big trouble.

Steps to change

1. Goto App dashboard
2. Goto publishing overview
   [image]
3. Click Manage & Select Managed publishing on
4. Hit save

We are done. Hoping like me it will save someone from great trouble