# How to delete one pending release in Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I uploaded one bundle in Google Play Console version 38 and created release, then this was moved to `In Review`

After 20 minutes later, someone noticed a bug that missed during QA session and I wanted to delete(cancell) this release but could not find any way to do it.

Then I created a new bundle version 39 and started a release for it, which is also "In Review"

I want to delete in review version 38 now so google team doesn't waste time with something that I don't even intend or want to release.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to cancel/delete a pending release review then reupload a new bundle with same version id ? (this would be perfect imo as avoid also bumping versions without need. Can make more code changes, bake bundle and upload again then create new release)
2. Assuming point 1 is not possible and we are in my current situation. Is it possible at least to cancel the pending review when I have a newer one ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cancel a pending release that is in review as of now. But if you upload the latest release, it should get approved quickly and just replace the old one so long as you have incremented the versioning codes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69690795/17987933

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Wow can't believe 5 years have passed since the previous question and still google has not implemented such a useful thing... Anyway thanks for the reply then I will wait for the 2 reviews to get approved and I publish manually the most recent one...

Comment: Yeah, I find it odd that they haven't yet. Apple allows for it (in fact you are required to remove previous versions from review before publishing new versions). Anyway, best of luck to you!